# Confused about some standard input or heredoc usage in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

[image]

As the image. All commands are similar.
I know how to use that, but I don't really know the detail.
Would anyone know that? Thank you very much.

```
# does `cat` read fd and print?
$ cat file

# does `cat` read from stdin and print?
$ cat < file

$ cat - < file

# with heredoc or herestring, what methods `cat` command use to read from heredoc?stdin?

$ cat << EOF
heredoc> test
heredoc> EOF
test

$ cat <<< "test"

$ cat - << EOF
heredoc> test
heredoc> EOF
test

$ cat - <<< "test"

# and I dont why these commands works?

$ cat <(echo "test")

$ cat - <<(echo "test")

# why this command doesn't work?

$ cat - <(echo "test")
```

Comment: I like your graphic - it makes for a good cheat sheet!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some reading material, all from the very useful Bash manual:

- [Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Input) (`<filename`) -- causes standard input to be redirected to the file `filename`
- [Here documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) (`<<WORD`) -- causes standard input to be redirected to the script source from the next line, up to but not including the line `WORD`
- [Here strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) (`<<<"string"`) -- causes standard input to be redirected to the string `string` (as though the string were written to a temporary file and then standard input redirected to that file)
- [Process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) (`<(command)`) -- starts a process executing `command` and inserts a name onto the command line which acts like a filename, such that reading from that "file" produces the output of the command

The use of `-` to indicate the the source file is standard input is common to many commands and recommended by Posix. Many commands read from standard input if no file is specified. Some, like `cat`, implement both ways of indicating that the intention is to read from standard input.

Note that `-` and `<(command)` are both filename arguments, while `<filename`, `<<WORD` and `<<<"string"` are redirections. So while they superficially look similar, they are quite different under the hood. What they have in common is that they have to do with *input*; some of them (but not here-docs/strings) have analogues that have to do with output, using `>` instead of `<`.

Comment: Thanks for these detailed explanation. You give me a big hand.

Comment: The wording of your "Here strings" explanation is a bit confusing to me. I wonder if other readers feel the same.